# Why induction cannot be used for infinite sets?

Tags: induction

Explain why induction cannot be used to conclude: $$\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)^c = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c$$

Comment: Hello! Could you please tell us where the problem comes from and what have you tried to solve it?

Comment: Loosely speaking: because there is no integer $n$ s.t. $n+1 = \infty$.

Comment: I just saw it in my textbook of Understanding Analysis. I think it has no problem if we find that n=1 holds, then assume n=m holds, and to prove n=m+1 holds, even for infinite n. I have no idea how to prove, but I thought that in principle this induction tool may be used to deal with infinite sets.

Comment: $n$ is not a free variable in the above expression - it is not a statement about $n$. @Edie

Comment: Not to mention that the more general statement $\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right)^c = \bigcap_{i\in I} A_i^c$ holds - with an arbitrary index set $I$.

Comment: Actually proving the equality is a question of basic logic. No induction necessary! Just consider what it takes to be a member of the set on the left, and of the set on the right. Then work out the equivalence of the two conditions.

Comment: That's what I am going to do in the next step. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: The lower-case n=1 is fixed. There is nothing we can do about ∞ since we never get to ∞, it that what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

The title is wrong. Induction *can* be used in the infinite set $\Bbb N$.

For all $N\in\Bbb N$
$$\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n\right)^c = \bigcap_{n=1}^N A_n^c$$
and this can be proved by induction. But you can't "jump" from any $N$ to $\infty$.

Nitpicking: there is a stonger induction: the [Transfinite induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction).

Comment: You didn't answer "why" you can't "jump from any $N$ to $\infty$." which is the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, because $\infty$ has no immediate predecessor/$\infty$ never is "the next $n$"/ the Winther comment.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at how your text defines the set $\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)$.  My guess is that it defines as the set of all elements $x$ for which there exists an $A_n\in \{A_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ with the property that $x\in A_n$.

To expand on the previous by Pinilla we can't conclude that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i} $ is finite even though $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{i}$ is finite for every positive integer $N$.

Answer (score 3):

Theorem: If $A_i$ is finite for every $i$, then:

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$$

is finite.

If you could use simple induction, wouldn't this be true?