# How to prove that conditional probability is bounded to [0,1]?

Tags: proof-verification, induction, problem-solving, conditional-probability

I am trying to solve the following question from Sheldon Ross, Introduction to Probability Models.

[image: chapter 1 question 47 sheldon ross]

I am struggling to prove the first of the 3 conditions,

[image: the 3 conditions for a probability]

I thought of using the inclusion exclusion theorem, but I can't think of how to prove these bounds for $ P(A_i \cup B)$ . I was thinking that showing $P(\phi | B) = 0$ and $P(\Omega |B) = 1 $ should be enough since $\phi \subseteq A_i \subseteq \Omega $. But I want rigor in my proof.

[image]

Now I think my proof for condition 2 is correct and straightforward. For condition 3, I used $n=2$ as the base case and proved it via induction. But I am not sure it is a valid proof since $\infty$ is not a natural number and [stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872716/induction-countable-union-of-countable-sets) seems to agree that it is not valid. I was wondering if induction is enough to show that [countable additivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXBxj.png) holds for any **countably infinite** sequence of events ${A_1, A_2, \cdots }$ which are mutually exclusive. When can I use induction to prove that it holds for an infinite of cases? What other tools are there?

My attempts -

[image: page 2 of my work]
[image: page 3 of my work]

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood your question, but it seems much simpler than you are making it.  As I understand it, you are trying to prove that $0 \le P(A \mid B) \le 1$ for all events $A,B$.  Well, just write the definition: $P(A \mid B) = P(A \cap B) / P(B)$.  This is a ratio of two nonnegative numbers, so it is nonnegative.  And $A \cap B \subset B$, so the numerator is less than or equal to the denominator.  Done.

Comment: @NateEldredge is there any proof for the fact that if A is a subset of B then P(A) must be less than P(B)? It seems obvious, but I thought the proof must be only depending on axioms and logic

Comment: Sure.  Write $B = A \cup (B \setminus A)$.  This is a disjoint union so by axiom (iii) we have $P(B) = P(A) + P(B \setminus A)$.  But by axiom (i) we have $P(B \setminus A) \ge 0$.  This implies $P(B) \ge P(A)$.

Comment:  thanks I can't believe I overcomplicated that. What about condition 3? Do you think the induction proof is good enough?

Comment: No, induction can prove your claim for finite unions, but not for infinite unions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $0\leq P(A\cap B)\leq P(B)$, it follows that

$$0\leq P(A\mid B)= \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}\leq 1$$

Here is a proof for (3):

$$P(\bigcup_n A_n\mid B) =\frac{P(\bigcup_n A_n\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
$$= \sum_n \frac{P(A_n\cap B)}{P(B)} = \sum_n P(A_n\mid B)$$

Comment: Any idea about if induction can be used to prove propery 3?

Comment: Induction on what? There is nothing to induct on. This is rather a straightforward calculation, which I added to my answer.

Comment: I mean that proof only holds for finite unions right? But the actual condition needs it to be proven for infinite number of unions.

Comment: The statement $B\cap \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i=\bigcup_{i\in I}(B\cap A_i)$ holds for every index set $I$, so not only finite ones. This is an easy set theory exercise.